# jQuery Focus in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery

I have a input type text for a search field and I'm using jQuery and Focus, but it's not working in Internet Explorer and I wonder if I have done something wrong in my code or if there is a better way to do it? Preciate some help! Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#search12_176db646136e9421c49d1b").focus();

});
```

The `#search12_176db646136e9421c49d1b` id the id of the input tag.

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/Awh5J/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

      setTimeout(function() {
         $("#search12_176db646136e9421c49d1b").focus();
      },1000);

    });
```

or

```
$("#search12_176db646136e9421c49d1b")[0].focus();
```

Here

```
$("#search12_176db646136e9421c49d1b")[0]
```

is similar to

```
document.getElementById('search12_176db646136e9421c49d1b')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('search12_176db646136e9421c49d1b').focus();
```